# TSQL Recursive Stored Procedure Addition not working

Tags: database, t-sql, stored-procedures, recursion, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble with my stored procedure. It is supposed to add the values of all children, subchildren etc from a given position up and return it. At the moment all it returns is `NULL`.

This is an example of a table the stored procedure will be used on.

Later I want to implement the operator Bool into the stored procedure as well. If it is `NULL`, the saldo is ignored in the calculation. If it is 0 the saldo is used negatively and if it is 1, the saldo is used positively.

```
id  pos             operpos     saldo   operator
-------------------------------------------------
1   blue            NULL        NULL    NULL
2   lightblue       blue        NULL    1
3   darkblue        blue        25.00   1
4   skyblue         lightblue   12.00   1
5   babyblue        lightblue   -12.00  0
6   greyblue        lightblue   22.00   1
7   royalblue       darkblue    121.00  1
8   navyblue        darkblue    20.00   1
9   sailorsblue     navyblue    23.00   0
10  captainsblue    navyblue    33.00   1
```

This is what the stored procedure for `calctotal(darkblue)` should calculate:

```
darkblue        +25
 royalblue      +121
 navyblue       +20
  sailorsblue   -23 //because operator = 0
  captainsblue  +33
OUTPUT          176
```

This is the stored procedure that I have at the moment:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[calctotal]
        //DECLARE INPUT AND OUTPUT
       @number nvarchar(255),
       @total NUMERIC(20,2) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
     //DECLARE THE VARIABLES
     DECLARE @pos NVARCHAR(255) = NULL;
     DECLARE @saldo NUMERIC(20,2) =  NULL;
     DECLARE @tmptotal NUMERIC(20,2)
     DECLARE @tmptotal2 NUMERIC(20,2) = 0;

     //LOAD DATA INTO CURSOR
     DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL for
        SELECT pos, saldo  
        FROM test 
        WHERE operpos = @number

     //START CURSOR AND FETCH NEXT
     OPEN CUR

     FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @pos, @tmptotal2

     //WHEN NEW ITEM HAS BEEN LOADED
     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
         //ADD VALUE TO TMPTOTAL
         SET @tmptotal = @tmptotal2 + @tmptotal;

         //RECURSIVE PART SO FUNCTION APPLIES TO CHILDREN
         EXEC calctotal @pos, @tmptotal;
     END;

     close cur
     deallocate cur

     //THE OUTPUT OF TOTAL IS SET TO THE VALUE OF THE VARIABLE
     SET @total = @tmptotal;
END
```

Do you guys have and Idea on what could be wrong with the code and/or how to correct it? For any hints on how to implement the Operator Boolean, I would be very glad!

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: First of all, please do not use CURSORS ! they are extremely bad for production, second, can you please provide us with sample data on how you want your end result to look based on the definition above? It's confusing at the moment. Thanks

Comment: @Claudio sorry for having been unclear. I added and for a calculation to the post.

Comment: @Claudio i am not sure how else i can get all the values from the hierarchy into an output recursively. That's why I used cursors. Do you have a suggestion on what to use instead of a cursor, so that the value of each child is parsed through?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to come up with a solution, doing testing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select pos, operpos, saldo, [operator], 0 as level
 from tbl
 where pos = 'darkblue'
 union all
 select t.pos,t.operpos, t.saldo, t.[operator], c.level + 1
 from tbl t 
 inner join cte c on c.pos = t.operpos
)

select sum (
case 
when [operator] = 0 then (-1 * saldo) 
when [operator] = 1 then saldo 
else 0 
end) as totalsum from cte
```

This is a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE), and is available from SQL Server 2005 onwards. We basically retrieved all the children for root value 'darkblue' and then did a conditional summation based on the `operator` field. Instead of hard coding, you can pass a parameter instead, like so:

```
...
where pos = @pos
...
```

Note that this approach deals with the data as a set, and removes the need to manually deal with cursors.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NBOX10767)

Comment: Thank you this is great!
Just one last question. Can I use this CTE inside a stored procedure with an inputvariable @colour and adding this variable to the cte as well (where pos = @colour)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. A tip on asking questions - always specify the version of your RDBMS, because features can be version dependent. For example, this solution won't work for SQL Server 2000.

Comment: thank you for the solution and for your tips! I would love to upvote your ansver, but i am not eligible yet.
I'm using SQL Server 2012, so this should work :)